# sprockets inside of sinatra outputs nil

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sprockets

I'm running sprockets inside of sinatra with the intention to integrate Opal with it as well (because I don't want two sprockets instances running at the same time).

I know my route is capturing the details correctly because with a bit of debugging I can see `["application", ".js"]` and `["application", ".css"]` being outputted into the log file, but the output of me doing `settings.assets["#{file_name}.#{extention}"]` is nil.

This is the code I'm running to to set up sprockets can be found at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Thermatix/6c7d579a4962cc905d72).

By doing:

```
        settings.assets.instance_exec(file_name,extention) do |file_name,extention|
            puts 'assets'
            puts @assets
            @assets[cache_key_for("#{file_name}#{extention}", {bundle: true})]
        end
```

It outputs:

```
assets
{}
```

I'm guessing that for some reason the asset cache is blank, why that is though I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after upgrading sprockets to "3.3" and opal-react to "react-v0.13" branch and fiddling with things I was able to  get it working.

I'm thinking it was a load path issue, not sure why, but it just wasn't finding any files which is strange because it wasn't raising an error either, just returning nil.

Any way, the solution lies in [this github repo](https://github.com/Thermatix/sprockets_problem).